# Quiero crear viajes y a esos viajes agregarle pasajeros. Logro hacerle pero creo viaje 1 y viaje 2. En el dos veo los viajes del uno y viceversa

Tags: json, backend

https://github.com/Enomao86/GestionViajes

Gente vengo a pedirles ayuda. En este repo agrego varios viajes pero cuando le agrego un pasajero a uno  me.lo muestra en todos. Y también al eliminar el viaje no se elimina los pasajeros del json

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te sugerimos agregar más información, revisa [ask], saludos.